# Packetizing an multimedia file (video or audio file)

Tags: java, android, network-programming, chunked-encoding

for an android project I must load a multimedia file and then send the multimedia file in chunks (by reading it from file system) to a server. I don't know how can I do this work. Please give me an example to how do this?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean to say 'packetize' here. Do you want to send the multimedia file in chunks (by reading it from file system) to a server?

Comment: yes! I exactly mean it. please tell me, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can play your as video or audio as streaming Please check this [link](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/sample-streaming-video-mediaplayer-or-how-to-stream-video-from-url-in-android)

Comment: Thats about downloading in chunks but the question is how to upload a large file in chunks...